# getting the value from a function and subtracting that value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to return a value from my function.. what am I doing wrong here?  I am trying to subtract the value from findCostOfService from the slider value that the jQuery ui is giving me.  Any thoughts?

```
 function findCostOfService(n) {
  n = 10;
}

 $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value: 100000,
        min: 100000,
        max: 5000000,
        step: 150000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

         $( "#increasedRevenueValue" ).val(ui.value - findCostOfService());
        }               
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findCostOfService() {
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: remember in your case no need to pass parameter

Comment: If this is the correct answer, than there is no need for a function either. Simply set the value without a function: `ui.value - findCostOfService()`

Comment: @JamesHill: hope you know always you don't need to use parameters for methods, functions. it is based on the requirement.

Comment: I hope you know that if you have a function that returns a static number like `10` with no calculation, you don't need a function at all.

Comment: i'm assuming he is doing some calculations and return value. i dont mind about your down vote,remember this is the only answer match with his usage(he doesn't need to pass parameter)

Comment: I down-voted because your answer offers no explanations and make assumptions.

Comment: @JamesHill: see the usage of the function in his question. and did you see any explanations in others answers to use parameters in the function?

Comment: We're not going to agree on this. Of all the answers, you're the only one who simply posted code with no explanation and no documentation links. This is a poor answer, hence my down-vote.

Comment: @JamesHill: As long as OP is thinking this is the answer i'm not worrying about down votes.

Comment: @JamesHill You're answer provided me a little insight, but not enough.  I chose this answer because of his comment immediately afterwards.  I was under the impression that you had to pass a parameter in order to return a value with a function.. and that's not the case.  I was really posting this question to learn more about passing values in functions.. Instead you down vote me.  Way to encourage others to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *return* a value.

```
function findCostOfService(n) {
    n = 10;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning your value, you're just setting a variable.

```
function findCostOfService(n) {
    n = 10;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return something from your function.

```
function findCostOfService(n) {
  n = 10;
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`return` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) to return a value:

```
function findCostOfService(n) {
    n = 10;        
    return n;
}
```

In addition, `findCostOfService` takes a parameter `n`, which you are not passing in:

```
$( "#increasedRevenueValue" ).val(ui.value - findCostOfService([SomeValueHere]));
                                    Pass value to your function ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Note:** Unless your code example is incomplete, you don't need a function in this situation. If a function is simply returning a simple value, with no calculation, a function is not needed. This would be sufficient:

```
$( "#increasedRevenueValue" ).val(ui.value - 10);
```

Comment: For some reason, when I return n I get the desired results, but when I pass n in the function, it breaks?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle, but for some reason I can't display the jquery ui slider?  http://jsfiddle.net/QkZwW/